# java Accessing global variable to another class(updating variables with actionperformed)

Tags: java, swing, global-variables

i am trying to access global variable of a class from another class the glass is giving me null value instead of enter value during action performed`

```
package com.audit;

    public class panel extends JPanel {
     String shost;
     String suser;
     String spass;
     int sport;
     public int getsport() {
           return this.sport;
        }
     public String getshost() {
           return this.shost;
        }
     public String getsuser() {
           return this.suser;
        }
     public String getspass() {
           return this.spass;
        }
    public panel(){
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 680;
        size.height = 600;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Linux Audit"));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();


        JLabel labelhost = new JLabel("Host    ");
        JLabel labeluser = new JLabel("User name    ");
        JLabel labelpass = new JLabel("Password    ");
        JLabel labelport = new JLabel("Port    ");
        final JTextField host = new JTextField(15);
        final JTextField user = new JTextField(15);
        final JTextField pass=(JTextField)new JPasswordField(15);
        final JTextField port = new JTextField(15);
        final JButton start = new JButton("Start Audit");
        //layout design
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.weighty = 0.5;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=0;
        add(labelhost,gc);
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=1;
        add(labeluser,gc);
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=2;
        add(labelpass,gc);
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=3;
        add(labelport,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=0;
        add(host,gc);
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=1;
        add(user,gc);
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=2;
        add(pass,gc);
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=3;
        add(port,gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.weighty=10;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=4;
        add(start,gc);
        //startaudit action

    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String shost = host.getText();
                String suser = user.getText();
                String spass = pass.getText();
                String sportb = port.getText();
                int sport = Integer.parseInt(sportb);

                sshConnection s = new sshConnection();
                s.Connection();
                /*System.out.println(shost);
                System.out.println(suser);
                System.out.println(spass);
                System.out.println(sport);*/

            }


        });


    }

}
```

in above i am trying to fetch the value of global variables

```
 String shost;
 String suser;
 String spass;
 int sport;
```

in another class

```
///another class

public class sshConnection {

    public void Connection(){
         String sshhost = new panel().getshost();
         String sshuser = new panel().getsuser();
         int sshport = new panel().getsport();
         String sshpass = new panel().getspass();
         System.out.println(sshhost);
         System.out.println(sshuser);
         System.out.println(sshport);
         System.out.println(sshpass);
    }
}
```

i am getting null values instead of inserted values at the time of execution.please solve the problem, i know its very basic but i m beginer.so plz help
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `panel` class, `shost`, `suser`, etc., aren't set to anything until you click on the Start Audit button.  But `Connection` constructs a 4 **new** `panel` objects.  Those won't be the same `panel` objects that you clicked the button on.  I think what you want to do is change your Connection method so that it takes a `panel` argument:

```
public void Connection(panel p){
    String sshhost = p.getshost();
    String sshuser = p.getsuser();
    ...
```

and change the `s.Connection` call inside your listener to

```
s.Connection (panel.this);
```

so that `Connection` knows what `panel` it's supposed to be working with.

Or, a better design might be to have `Connection` take the three strings and the integer as arguments, and not bother with `getshost()`, etc., at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys But, it will be good if you can give me some more details about connection taking arguments and calling connection inside actionperforment. @ajb i tried your way still not working maybe i am missing something, it will be better fot me if you can give some more details

Comment: Thanks for such a nice replies god bless.....got the desired output...Hope to have support like this in future too.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating multiple instances of `panel` in `sshConnection#Connection` whose fields are `null`.

The values from the existing instance of `panel` need to be used. I suggest simply pass them as parameters instead

```
public void performConnection(String sshHost, String sshUser, int sshPort, String sshPass){
 ...
}
```

Java Naming Conventions show that classes start with a *uppercase* letter, e.g. `SshConnection` while methods start with a *lowecase* letter, e.g. `performConnection`. Read [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)